# Unexpected token when trying to iterate over Object

Tags: reactjs

Why do I get "Unexpected token error for semicolon. I am trying to iterate over a object that has 5 child objects using React and JSX. The error pointing to the following line. Thank you.

```
Object.keys(movies).map((movie) => console.log(movie.id));
```

Below is how I have the entire App.js file coded.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


const profiles = [
  {
    id: 1,
    userID: '1',
    favoriteMovieID: '1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    userID: '2',
    favoriteMovieID: '1',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    userID: '4',
    favoriteMovieID: '5',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    userID: '5',
    favoriteMovieID: '2',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    userID: '3',
    favoriteMovieID: '5',
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    userID: '6',
    favoriteMovieID: '4',
  },
];

const users = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Jane Jones',
    userName: 'coder',
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Matthew Johnson',
    userName: 'mpage',
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Autumn Green',
    userName: 'user123',
  },
  4: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'John Doe',
    userName: 'user123',
  },
  5: {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Lauren Carlson',
    userName: 'user123',
  },
  6: {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Nicholas Lain',
    userName: 'user123',
  },
};

const movies = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Planet Earth',
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Selma',
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Million Dollar Baby',
  },
  4: {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Forrest Gump',
  },
  5: {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Get Out',
  },
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">ReactND - Coding Practice</h1>
        </header>
        <h2>How Popular is Your Favorite Movie?</h2>
        {
            <h2>
                { 
                    Object.keys(movies).map((movie) => console.log(movie.id)); 

                }
            </h2>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The error comes from the semicolon in your component after the Object.keys call. But to fix your code you probably want to switch to Object.values to only get the movies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over object keys, you can use the `[]` notation to access the values as `Object.keys` returns an array of object's keys.

Additionally, there is no need to wrap the `h2` element with `{}` as it's already a valid `JSX`.

[image: Edit youthful-paper-31e4k]

```js
 class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>{Object.keys(movies).map(movie => movies[movie].name) + " "}</h2>
        <h2>{Object.keys(users).map(user => users[user].userName) + " "}</h2>
        <h2>
          {Object.keys(profiles).map(
            profile => profiles[profile].favoriteMovieID
          ) + " "}
        </h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```